# set animation in android?

Tags: android

In my application i use the single Activity.

Here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Animation2 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Show1();
}

private void Show1() {
    LinearLayout linLay = new LinearLayout(this);
    linLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("This is form 1");

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("Go to Form 2");
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Show2();
        }
    });

    linLay.addView(tv);
    linLay.addView(btn);

    Animation animation=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,Animation.ZORDER_NORMAL, 300);
    animation.setDuration(1500);
    linLay.setAnimation(animation);
    setContentView(linLay);

}

protected void Show2() {
    LinearLayout linLay = new LinearLayout(this);
    linLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("This is form 2");

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("Back to form 1");
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Show1();
        }
    });

    linLay.addView(tv);
    linLay.addView(btn);

    Animation animation=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,Animation.ZORDER_NORMAL, 300);
    animation.setDuration(1500);
    linLay.setAnimation(animation);
    setContentView(linLay);
}
```

}

when i call the function Show1() and show2() i wish to show the animation like a intent action.How to do this?

Comment: See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796589/how-do-i-add-a-tween-animation-to-my-custom-view)

Answer (score 2):

Try `linLay.startAnimation(animation);` instead of `linLay.setAnimation(animation);`.